# Can I put Snackbar above Bottom Navigation?

Tags: android, layout, android-snackbar

My scenario is that I have a created a single class `Snackbar Display` which displays a particular snackbar. So I am calling this `Snackbar` class from various Activities and Fragments and all of them have a bottom navigation in them. Is there a way to display the Snackbar above the bottom navigation? I can't use any navigation id as it will keep changing from Activity to activity which is calling it.

Answer (score 0):

> Snackbars appear above all other elements on screen and only one can
>   be displayed at a time (javadoc)

You can try displaying this snackbar layout as any other view inside a framelayout to display above bottom navigation. And if your bottom navigation is a common fragment, you can add snackbar view in that layout only aligning it above your navigation bar.

Add enter exit animations to this snackbar layout and it will look as if it is snackbar.

Comment: By doing this then I will have to add snack bar in all layout files. Can't this be done by some other way? And by above I meant that navigation bar and snackbar shouldn't overlap.

Comment: You won't be able to use android Snackbar widget to achieve non-overlapping views as intended as it appears above everything on screen. You have to create your own view/fragment which looks like a snackbar.